# Is it ever quicker to use an index on a one-column table?

Tags: mysql, database, indexing

Purely for performance, is there ever a reason to create an index on a one-column table in mysql?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, why you expect a single column table (as comapred to multicolumn) be somehow different in aspect of how indices works? I see no single reason for any difference in performance considerations for a single column table vs. multicolumn table.

Basically I mean that any situation where engine is using *index* vs. *sequental* search will be the same for any type of table.

Comment: I think it shouldn't have an effect, just want to make sure.